# Как запретить изменения размера программы Python Eel

Tags: python

Решил попробывать сделать интерфейс через EEL библиотеку. Но столкнулся с проблемой, мне нужно запретить менять размер окна. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: У вас получилось найти решение?

Comment: @Ростислав Привет, да

Comment: Это невозможно! В документации такого нет.

Comment: @Петрович возможно с помощью js